# Play: Reads vs Form

Tags: json, validation, parsing, playframework, httprequest

I am creating an HTTP REST API with JSON formats.

Play seems to offer two completely separate ways to parse and validate my input:

- `play.api.data.Form`
- `play.api.libs.json.Reads`

What are the differences between these, and which would be better suited for parsing JSON request bodies, with validation and error handling?

If "it depends", what does it depend on?

Answer (score 2):

For parsing a request with a JSON body, it's `Reads` all the way. In fact, there really is no way to use a `Form` for parsing JSON, as that's not what it's meant for. `Form`s are entirely for binding to and form URL-encoded forms (i.e. `String -> String` key value pairs), and that's it.

That aside, they're actually very similar in terms of validation and error handling. I'm certain that was done purposefully. They both contain the same, or very similar validation methods such as `min`, `max`, `minLength`, `verifying`, etc. Both `bindFromRequest` and `validate` handle errors in such a way that they accumulate instead of failing fast, and both have `fold` methods for handling errors easily:

```
someForm.bindFromRequest.fold (
    formWithErrors => ...,
    value => ...
)

request.body.validate[A].fold (
    errors => ... ,
    value => ...
)
```

Though not applicable for everyone, there are also [JSON transformers](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaJsonTransformers), which offer powerful functional ways of manipulating JSON structures before and after (or never) binding to an object.

REST API or not, I tend to use JSON validation as much as possible, as it feels much less clunky than `Form`s, and is generally easier to compose smaller `Reads` and `Writes` together.